# Storing arbitrary metadata with a plain-text file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am writing a text-editor and I would need to store a few pieces of information (generally just a few strings; the storage needn't be particularly durable) with each file the app saves (without that being part of the text-file as other apps might read it and the info is only specific to my app).

How would I go about this?

---

More info: I have a NSDocument set up and I would like to simply store a NSString instance variable as a per file meta-datum. Based on the answers below I've come up with this, which is currently buggy and causes the program to crash on startup:

```
#import <sys/xattr.h>
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument {
  NSString *metadatum;
}

@implementation MyDocument 

- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)type error:(NSError **)err
{
  BOOL output = [super writeToURL:url ofType:type error:err];
  if(!setxattr([[url path] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 
               "eu.gampleman.xattrs.style", 
               [metadatum cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 
               sizeof(char) * [styleName length], 0, 0)) 
  {
      NSLog(@"Write failure");
  }
  return output;
}

- (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)type error:(NSError **)err {
  char *output;
  ssize_t bytes = getxattr([[url path] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                           "eu.gampleman.xattrs.style", &output, 1024, 0, 0);
  if (bytes > 0) {
    metadatum = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:output length:bytes 
          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // <- crashes here with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
  }
  return [super readFromURL:url ofType:type error: err];
}

// ...
// fairly standard -dataOfType:error: and 
// -readFromData:ofType:error: implementations
```

---

PS: If your answer is really good (with sample code, etc.), I will award a 100rep bounty.

Comment: Use `-[NSString fileSystemRepresentation]` instead of `-cStringUsingEncoding:`. An `NSString`'s length is in UTF-16 characters, which is not the same length as it will be in UTF-8 characters (except for pure ASCII). The `getxattr()` call is passing a pointer to a pointer, which is 4 or 8 bytes of storage, but saying it's 1024 bytes. You have likely corrupted the stack or heap. You have to allocate storage of the proper size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use extended attributes.  See [setxattr()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man2/setxattr.2.html).

Here's a sample call to write a string:

```
NSData* encodedString = [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int rc = setxattr("/path/to/your/file", "com.yourcompany.yourapp.yourattributename", [encodedString bytes], [encodedString length], 0, 0);
if (rc)
    /* handle error */;
```

To read a string:

```
ssize_t len = getxattr("/path/to/your/file", "com.yourcompany.yourapp.yourattributename", NULL, 0, 0, 0);
if (len < 0)
    /* handle error */;
NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:len];
len = getxattr("/path/to/your/file", "com.yourcompany.yourapp.yourattributename", [data mutableBytes], len, 0, 0);
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

PS: Don't you have to set the bounty on the question before it's answered?

Comment: Not really, I can set it later on (though I have to wait two days to be able to do it). Also thanks for the reference, any examples on how I may use it (read, write)?

Comment: At the bottom of the linked man page, there are links to `getxattr()`, `listxattr()`, and `removexattr()`.

Comment: Updated answer with trivial example of setting an attribute. If you want more specifics, you need to explain more about what you're trying to save. If it's an object subgraph, you can make it `NSCoding`-compliant and archiving into an `NSData` and write that.

Comment: I edited the question to add a bit more detail, I'm trying to save a simple NSString.

Comment: I updated my answer with code to write and read an `NSString`.

Comment: Just to ping you about the impending bounty, if you shape up the answer a bit, I'll award it to you.

Comment: Thanks but not interested. I enjoy answering questions but don't particularly care about reputation. I provided as good an answer as I care to.

Comment: Ken provided an answer with sample code for reading and writing xattrs specific to your needs.  What else do you think it needs to earn the bounty?

Comment: @sbooth I ended up giving it to him anyway (why waste a good 100rep). There is quite a bit more that could be added - analysis of advantages/disadvantages of this approach (i.e. does it persist when sending to other computers?), how to best integrate into the nsdocument architecture, etc. I know that is asking well over and beyond what is normally expected of an answer, but that's why it's a bounty. (Also I have only given out only a few bounties and so I'm experimenting a bit of how the system actually works and how I can use it.)

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks for this code. Very helpful. Just one nit. In the getter snippet, you have `NSData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:len]`. This causes a compiler error. If you change the declaration to `NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:len]`, everything is perfect. Thanks again for the concise answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

There are several places to store this kind of information on Mac. The most simple, of course, is to store it in your own separate metadata database. Of course there are challenges if the file moves. Since 10.6, however, you can use Bookmarks to address this problem. A Bookmark (see [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) allows you to keep a reference to a file even if it is moved (even across application restarts). Prior to 10.6 there was the Alias Manager, but it couldn't create new aliases; just read ones that Finder created.

The next common solution is to create metadata files. So if I have `foo.txt`, then you create a sibling `.foo.txt.metadata` to hold the extra info. Several trade-offs there if the files can be moved around.

Next is Spotlight, which can be used to attach arbitrary information to files. The actual tool here is xattr (see the man pages for `setxattr` and its relatives). These basically absorb several things that used to be done with Resource Forks (except xattr is supposed to just be metadata).

Comment: The information is good (I like the overview of approaches) but perhaps more ideas on how to actually use some of this stuff would be neat (links to tutorial material would be great).