# Finding Macintosh file's attributes

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, attributes, mac-classic

I will illustrate a use case of my issue.

I have here two files which happen to be the `Finder 7.5.5` and `Finder 8.1` from legacy Mac OS versions.

If I use `Cmd + I` I get the following information:

```
Version:
7.5.5, © Apple Computer, Inc. 1983-96
System 7.5 Version 7.5.3
```

and

```
Version:
8.1, Copyright Apple Computer, Inc. 1983-97
Mac OS 8.1
```

I want to extract these information programatically. However, I am not even sure where it is being hold.

In a small Objective-C project (Foundation) I did the following for the `7.5` file:

```
NSString      * finder7     = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"/Users/me/Desktop/Finder7"];
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError       * error       = nil;
NSDictionary  * attr        = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:finder7 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", attr);
```

This is the output:

```
2013-09-25 10:53:30.224 GetAttributes[1164:903] {
    NSFileCreationDate = "1996-01-15 12:00:00 +0000";
    NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 20;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = staff;
    NSFileHFSCreatorCode = 1296122707;
    NSFileHFSTypeCode = 1179534418;
    NSFileModificationDate = "1996-01-15 12:00:00 +0000";
    NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileOwnerAccountName = me;
    NSFilePosixPermissions = 493;
    NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
    NSFileSize = 0;
    NSFileSystemFileNumber = 4384377;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 234881026;
    NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;
}
```

As you can see, there is no reference to version or copyright. I can't open the "app's content" because legacy applications obviously don't have it.

So I figured it could be an extended attribute, so I got the console and did this:

```
$ ls -l@
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 me    staff          0 15 Jan  1996 Finder7
        com.apple.FinderInfo           32
        com.apple.ResourceFork     503994
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 me    staff    3631000 16 Dec  1997 Finder8
        com.apple.FinderInfo           32
        com.apple.ResourceFork     502012
        com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment        42
```

Then I found these entries in each of them:

```
$ xattr -l com.apple.FinderInfo Finder7
(...)
00077AE0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00077AF0  00 00 32 07 55 80 00 00 00 05 37 2E 35 2E 35 25  |..2.U.....7.5.5%|
00077B00  37 2E 35 2E 35 2C 20 A9 20 41 70 70 6C 65 20 43  |7.5.5, . Apple C|
00077B10  6F 6D 70 75 74 65 72 2C 20 49 6E 63 2E 20 31 39  |omputer, Inc. 19|
00077B20  38 33 2D 39 36 00 00 00 2B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |83-96...+.......|
(...)

$ xattr -l com.apple.FinderInfo Finder8
(...)
00077330  06 46 69 6E 64 65 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 08 10  |.Finder......6..|
00077340  80 00 00 00 03 38 2E 31 2B 38 2E 31 2C 20 43 6F  |.....8.1+8.1, Co|
00077350  70 79 72 69 67 68 74 20 41 70 70 6C 65 20 43 6F  |pyright Apple Co|
00077360  6D 70 75 74 65 72 2C 20 49 6E 63 2E 20 31 39 38  |mputer, Inc. 198|
00077370  33 2D 39 37 00 00 00 26 01 08 10 80 00 06 46 69  |3-97...&......Fi|
00077380  6E 64 65 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |nder............|
(...)
```

I never really used extended attributes, specially in a development. So here I need some light. I see the version numbers are in different positions. How can I get this information straight like the OSX Finder does? I spent several minutes to do it manually and still is not clear to me how the version is stored. Is there other place I can find this information or am I going in the right direction?

Are there Objective-C or C solutions that will do this so I don't need to reinvent the wheel?

I appreciate the help!

[image: File information windows]

I also tried checking `rsrc`. Found an easter egg just before the version number.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is a help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374580/storing-arbitrary-metadata-with-a-plain-text-file

Comment: If you want to see the content of the FinderInfo, you should use `xattr -p -l com.apple.FinderInfo Finder7`.  Without the -p, as you wrote it, the com.apple.FinderInfo would be taken as a file name, so the data you showed probably actually came from the resource fork.

Comment: That's not really an Easter egg, it's a phrase that uses all the letters of the alphabet, and was used to show what a font looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is stored in the extended attribute `com.apple.ResourceFork`. You can use a tool like [`DeRez`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/DeRez.1.html) to decompile the information.

If you want to programatically access the resource fork, there is the [Resource Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Resource_Manager/Reference/reference.html) API, but pretty much everything there is deprecated for 10.8. The resource type for version information is the `'vers'` resource.

Comment: Oh dear. Just out of curiosity: Does Finder decompile it every time? I am checking right now, Petesh, thanks!

Comment: I believe it caches it into the `com.apple.FinderInfo` on first request

Comment: @Apollo: Finder probably uses the deprecated Resource Manager routines.