# Modifying NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID attribute of file in NSFileManager not getting update

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager, update-attributes

I need to modify my file properties. There is a property `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID` which apple says it can be modified but when I am modifying it, it is not getting updated.
I also tried to first modify the permissions to 0777 but still it does not work.

**Code:**

```
   NSFileManager *filemgr;
   NSDictionary *attribs;
   NSArray *dirPaths;
   NSString *docsDir;
   filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray * filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: docsDir  error:NULL];
    NSError *error;
    for(int i=0;i<[filePathsArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *fullPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",filePath]];
        attribs = [filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:
                   docsDir error: NULL];
        NSLog (@"POSIX Permissions %@", [attribs objectForKey: NSFilePosixPermissions]);
        NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attribs];
        [attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithShort:0777]
                      forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions]; // chmod permissions 777
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:docsDir error:&error];
        NSLog(@"updated: %@",[filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:
                   docsDir error: NULL]);
        NSDictionary *dict2 = [filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:
                                          docsDir error: NULL];
        NSMutableDictionary *attributes2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict2];
        [attributes2 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:12345]forKey:NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]setAttributes:attributes2 ofItemAtPath:docsDir error:&error];
        NSLog(@"updated2: %@",[filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:
                              docsDir error: NULL]);
    }
```

"**[URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW4)**"

**UPDATE 2:**

Modifying only single attribute:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:12345]forKey:NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID];

     BOOL check=   [[NSFileManager defaultManager]setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:docsDir error:&error];
```

Still it gives error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x8d0b900 {NSFilePath=/Users/a/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/81ADKJ1A2-B612-4784-9524-05456F323212/Documents, NSUnderlyingError=0x8d11b80 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

Please suggest how to modify the property.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're running as the super-user, you can only change the group of files that you own. Furthermore, you can only change the group to a group that you're a member of.

You should not use a dictionary full of the current attributes of the file. Construct a dictionary with only the attributes you want to change. Otherwise, the system may think you're trying to "change" attributes that you're not and fail because it can't do everything you (apparently) asked.

You should check the return value from the `-setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method to see if it fails. If it does, you need to examine the error object it provides to see why.

---

Update: By the way, you can always drop down to the POSIX API for these types of file operations. Sometimes, Cocoa isn't the best API for low-level operations and being closer to the metal can be clearer.

```
int result;
do
{
    result = chown([docsDir fileSystemRepresentation], -1, 12345);
}
while (result != 0 && errno == EINTR);
if (result != 0)
    /* handle error; examine errno to learn failure reason */;
```

(In this case, though, judging by the error you logged, I'm sure that `errno` will be `EPERM` (1).)

Comment: Please see the edit question. I tried to do what you suggested, but still it is giving the same error. I have added the error also. Please help.

Comment: Do you own the file? Is your user account a member of group 12345?

Comment: Yes I have created the file using the code: NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",
                      @"Two",
                      @"Three",
                      @"Four", nil];
    NSString *filePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingFormat:@"/myfile.plist"];
    [array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"file Stored at %@",filePath);  I want to set my custom value to any attribute, so I tried to modify the NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID  value to my random value 12345. It does not relate with any group. Please suggest if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: First, your code all along has been operating on `docsDir`, not `filePath`. Second, you won't be allowed to set the group to an arbitrary number. It has to be the ID of an actual group to which your user account belongs. It sounds like you're trying to use the group to hold arbitrary metadata. Terrible plan, even if it could work. Use [extended attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374580/storing-arbitrary-metadata-with-a-plain-text-file/10374716#10374716).

Comment: You mean to say that I cannot modify any attribute value to any arbitrary metadata. Also which user account is referenced for the group. Please suggest.

Comment: Please suggest what? I don't understand the point of your last comment. I already suggested: if you want to store arbitrary metadata with a file, use extended attributes. The system imposes restrictions on what you can do with the standard attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am successfully able to add the extended attributes of file. Thank you.